# How can you animate automatic resizing of a grid row due to content change in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to animate the automatic change in height of a grid row that is set to auto:

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="top">Top content</div>
  <div id="bottom">Bottom content</div>
</div>
```

The **top** div height is automatically (auto) calculated based on the content.

When the content in the div changes such that it must resize (due to more or less content), how can I animate the automatic re-sizing itself (I'm not changing the grid-template-rows value)?

Comment: Hi ! I made your code a runnable StackOverflow snippet (the `<>` button). People can much easier test your code and there's even a "Copy snippet to answer" button to post a fix. You haven't posted any animation in the CSS so of course it won't animate. Would you post your attempt(s) so far as well?

Comment: You can't animate/transition to/from `auto`.

Comment: In that case, is there another solution to achieve the same effect?  Basically the top div needs to be re-sized based on its content and when it does re-size, that re-sizing should be animated.

Comment: You'll need javascript for that but I assume you are already using that to change the content of the element.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25861096/div-animate-auto-height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need javascript:

something like this:

```css
 #grid {
      display: grid;
      height: 100%;
      grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
    }

    #top {
      overflow: hidden; 
      transition: height 0.5s ease;
    }
```

then javascript:

```js
<script>
  function updateContent(newContent) {
    document.getElementById('top').innerHTML = newContent;

    setTimeout(() => {
      adjustTopHeight();
    }, 10);
  }

  function adjustTopHeight() {
    const topDiv = document.getElementById('top');
    topDiv.style.height = 'auto';
    const newHeight = topDiv.offsetHeight + 'px'; 
    topDiv.style.height = newHeight; 
  }


  setTimeout(() => {
    updateContent('UPDATED');
  }, 2000);
</script>
```